# Escaping special characters in "str_replace" PHP function

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

I have the below function with `str_replace`:

```
function url_seo($text)
{
    $match    = array(']','\\',';',"'",',','.','/','~','`','=');
    $replace  = array('-','','','','','','','','','');
    $text     = str_replace($match, $replace, $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Should I place a `\` before all the characters in the `$match` variable like this:

```
$match = array('\]','\\','\;',"\'",'\,','\.','\/','\~','\`','\=');
```

or there is no need to?

Comment: Nope, only behind those which need to be escaped. Like this `'\'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [str_replace PHP reference](http://php.net/str_replace),

> `search`
>   The **value being searched for**, otherwise known as the *needle*. An **array** may be used to designate multiple *needles*.

So, this is no regular expression, and you do not have to escape any characters except the [escape sequences](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/2/6/2/escape-sequences) that must always be escaped.

> `\"` Print the next character as a double quote, not a string closer
>   `\'` Print the next character as a single quote, not a string closer
>   `\n` Print a new line character
>   `\t` Print a tab character
>   `\r` Print a carriage return (not used very often)
>   `\$` Print the next character as a dollar, not as part of a variable
>   `\\` Print the next character as a backslash, not an escape character

So, only `\` in your array of strings should be escaped.

Depending on the string qualifier symbol, you may also have to escape `'` and `"`, but you can just alternate them as you already did: `'"'` and `"'"` is a good way to avoid over-escaping.